# Salesforce QueryResult - how to get relationship column data from results

Tags: soap-api

Using the Salesforce SOAP API to query some data from accountContactRole table. What is the best way to get a relationship value from the query result. When I perform the query in workbench or developer query editor it returns the correct data but I need to know how from my SOAP API VB.NET code would I get the Contact.Contact_Number__c value from the queryResult object?

```
 soql = String.Format("SELECT AccountId, ContactId, Contact.Contact_Number__c FROM AccountContactRole where accountid = '{0}' and role = '{1}' limit 1", salesforceAccountId, roleName)

        qr = binding.query(soql)
        If qr.records.Length = 1 Then
            Return qr.records(0) <<<<<<<----------- How to pull out contact.contact_number__c
        End If
```

Comment: It should be as simple as `qr.records(0).Contact.Contact_Number__c`, isn't it?

Comment: @sfdcfox that is what I initially tried but didn't work, once I cast the value to the AccountContactRole I was able to get at the properties from my answer I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to do this by casting the queryResult to an AccountContactRole and voila!

```
(DirectCast(qr.records(0), EnterpriseSF.AccountContactRole)).Contact.Contact_Number__c
```